# HANA Express in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hana

Is HANA Express still available in GCP ? Earlier I used it and  can still see $165 and 155 days left in free trial. But then when I am trying to search HANA from "Deploy Prebuilt application"  I am not getting any hit .

[GCP Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFmqd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also noticing this behavior recently, when I contacted the SAP, they said there is an issue going on currently with the HXE installation available,  it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks Sreekanth . I raised an incident with Google and waiting for their input . Shall update and  close the question soon .

Comment: It is fixed day before yesterday, I thought of just letting you know.